# I'm trying to implement Spring Security authentication based on data I have in my H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, h2

I'm trying to set up basic authentication(username and password), when I create users like this:

```
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        UserDetails staff = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("john")
                .password("john")
                .roles(Role.STAFF_MEMBER.toString())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, staff);
    }
```

I have no problem with log-in.
As I understand this just for testing purpose, so now I'm trying to implement authentication based on users I have in my database(for now I'm using h2 db, and using h2-console to see users in my database).Also I understand that later I'm going to use a real database instead of h2 which is in-memory db.
I have a data.sql file where I create one user just to test if login is going to work as it did with code above.
data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO employee (id,username,password,role) VALUES ('a48b0d24-9fe5-4a69-84ac-c9f8b63feb0a','admin', 'admin',0)
```

I've put role as zero because in my model.Employee I use @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)

```
Employee.java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Role role;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Department department;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "minimal_vacation_day_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VacationDay minimalVacationDay;



    //private int total_vacation_days; // moze bit field, ali bolje kalk. vrijednost
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employee_bonusvacdays",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bonus_vacation_day_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    )
    private Set<BonusVacationDay> bonusVacationDays = new HashSet<>();
    private LocalDateTime dateEmployed;

}
```

I followed a tutorial https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/spring-security-userdetailsservice/
and tried to implement UserDetailsService just like in tutorial but I fail.
EmployeeDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findByUsername(username);
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername(employee.get().getEmail()).password(employee.get().getPassword()).authorities(employee.get().getRole().toString()).build();
        return user;
    }
}
```

I also added a Bean to my Configuration file:

```
    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }
```

After I'have set up this configuration when I try to login i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: username cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:118) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: username cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:204) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User$UserBuilder.username(User.java:357) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(User.java:216) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at com.incompatibleTypes.plancation.plancationapp.service.EmployeeDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(EmployeeDetailsService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 57 common frames omitted

2024-01-17T12:48:34.238+01:00 DEBUG 4844 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /log-in?error
2024-01-17T12:48:34.247+01:00 DEBUG 4844 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /log-in?error
2024-01-17T12:48:34.256+01:00 DEBUG 4844 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /log-in?error
```

This is the whole Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
    }
    @Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(
                                mvc.pattern("/"),
                                mvc.pattern("/home"),
                                mvc.pattern("/log-in")
                        ).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )

                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()) // bez ovoga POST request ne radi - Postman ne prepoznaje tip autentikacije
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/log-in") // kada korisnik pristupa enpointu koji je secure-an, redirecta ga na login.html page
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login") // ovaj login nije moj custom nego endpoint od spring security-a koji ima mehanizam koji hendla autentifikaciju
                        .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                )

                .build();
    }

    // ***  TEST   When authenticated with different roles redirect to corresponding UserInterface(templates -> adminPage.html/staffPage.html)   TEST    ***
    // ***  TEST_RESULT -> OK
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        UserDetails staff = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("mario")
                .password("mario")
                .roles(Role.STAFF_MEMBER.toString())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, staff); // iako je H2 in memory database, ovaj korisnik se ne vidi u H2 konzoli - pitanje: želimo li to ili cu imat data file koji ce preloadat admin-a
    }
    // ***  TEST   When authenticated with different roles redirect to corresponding UserInterface(templates -> adminPage.html/staffPage.html)    TEST    ***

    // Code above is hard coded for test purpose, now I need to implement authentication based on database data
    // ***  I tried implementing UserDetailsService interface
    // except my custom implementation EmployeeUserDetailsService I added code below
    // ERROR -> when I try to log-in I get
    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }
```

So as I explained before I was expecting to log in but I got the `username cannot be null` error

Comment: You are using email as a username instead of username, and apparently there is no username being set. Also you are abusing `Optional` here, instead of the uglies you have use the `map` method. Something like `return employee.map( (emp) -> User.withUsername(emp.getUsername()).password(emp.getPassword()).authorities(emp.getRole().toString()).build()).orElseThrow( () -> new UserNotFoundExcepction("Some Message Here");`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me!
(Also I didn't check the optional yet, first time I've seen it so i just kinda copy pasted it).
Cheers

Comment: I hope this is just a learning example and you don't actually throw raw passwords at your database

Comment: @julaine Ofcourse! I'm just learning stuff so I haven't got to the part where I protect the users information(right now I don't have a clue about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in the mapping is using `email` as the username and not the actual `username`. You aren't inserting an `email` so it is `null` which will not work when mapping that to a `User` as a `username` is required.

Next to that you are a bit abusing (or not understanding) how to use `Optional`. Instead of what you now have use the `map` method instead.

```java
@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findByUsername(username);
        return employee
                 .map( this::toUser )
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User with name '"+username+"' not found!");
    }

    private User toUser(Employee emp) {
      return User
               .withUsername(emp.getUsername())
               .password(emp.getPassword())
               .authorities(emp.getRole().toString()).build();
    }
}
```

You don't need the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` bean method. Spring Security will automatically pickup your `UserDetailsService` bean. No need to make it more complex then that.

Comment: You are right, I have no idea how Optional works, first time I see it (I'm a noobie).
Thanks for the tip!
I have two questions:
1)
In your toUser function, did you mean to return UserDetails instead of User ?
2)
Also when I comment out DaoAuthenticationProvider bean method looks like Spring Security doesn't pick it up...my login is not working without it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: `User` is a `UserDetails` as it implements that interface. It should be picked up if you are on any recent Spring Security / Spring Boot version. Maybe something in your configuration prevents that (if you still have the `InMemory` stuff lingering around remove it as that doesn't help).